# trying to get sprite to disappear from screen after certain amount of time

Tags: python, pygame

i am trying to get my explosion image to disappear after a bullet collision with an alien. i am able to get the explosion to appear when the collision happens but can't seem to get it to disappear afterwards. i would like the explosion image to disappear after maybe 1 second or so. i understand that it would possibly involve a game clock and a kill method? thank you.

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien
from pygame.sprite import Sprite 

class AlienInvasion:
    """overall class to manage game assets and behavior"""

    def __init__(self):
        """initialize that game and create game resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))



        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self._create_fleet()
        # set the background color
        

        # set the background color

        


    def run_game(self):
        """start the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            
            

            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_aliens()
            self._update_screen()
            

    
    
    def _check_events(self):
        """respond to keypress and mouse events"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)


    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """respons to key presses"""

        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True

        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True 

        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit() 

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """ respond to key releases """
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False

        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False  


    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """create a new bullet and add it to the bullet group"""
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:

            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)




    def _update_bullets(self):
        """update positions of the bullets and get rid of old bullets"""
        # update bullet position

        self.bullets.update()

        # get rid of bullets that have disappeared

        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)



        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(self.bullets, self.aliens, 
            True, True)

        for collision in collisions:

        
            expl = Explosion(collision.rect.center)
            self.all_sprites.add(expl)





    def _update_aliens(self):
        """update the positions of all the aliens in the fleet"""

        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()




    def _create_fleet(self):
        
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_place = alien.rect.x
        alien_other_place = alien.rect.y

        for row_number in range(4):
            for alien_number in range(9):
                alien = Alien(self)
                alien.rect.x = alien_place + 110 * alien_number
                alien.rect.y =  alien_other_place + 120 * row_number

                self.aliens.add(alien)



    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        for alien in self.aliens:
           if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break              


    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        for alien in self.aliens:
            alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed    


        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

            

                
    


    def _update_screen(self):
        """update images on the screen and flip to the new screen"""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.draw_bullet()

        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        
        
      



        pygame.display.flip() 

class Explosion(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, center):
        super().__init__()

        
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/explo.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # make a game instance, and run the game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add another group for the explosions and to add the new `Explosion` object to this group, too:

```py
class AlienInvasion:
    # [...]

    def __init__(self):
        # [...]

        self.explosions = pygame.sprite.Group()

    # [...]

    def _update_bullets(self):
        # [...]

        for collision in collisions:

            expl = Explosion(collision.rect.center)
            self.explosions.add(expl)
            self.all_sprites.add(expl)
```

Get the current time ([`pygame.time.get_ticks()`)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) when the `Explosion` object is constructed and [`kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) the object in the update method after a certain time span:

```py
class Explosion(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, center):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/explo.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        
        self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() 

    def update(self):

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() 
        timespan = 1000 # 1000 milliseconds = 1 second

        if current_time > self.start_time + timespan:
            self.kill()
```

Do not forget to invoke `self.explosions.update()` in `AlienInvasion._update_bullets`:

```py
class AlienInvasion:
    # [...]

    def _update_bullets(self):
        # [...]

        self.explosions.update()
```

Comment: thank you so very much, this is brilliant and works perfectly. i'm just wondering for my own clarification why one has to add the second group for Explosions and why the kill() method couldn't just work on the all_sprites() group?

Comment: @SarabSingh 1. You have to add the group `self.explosions`, because you want to invoke the `update` for the explosions and not for all sprites. `self.explosions` contains only the `Explosion` objects. Note,not all sprites have an `update` method. 2. `kill()` removes the sprite from all groups.

Comment: i see, that makes sense to me. thank you so very much for all of your help. i greatly appreciate it!!